# Clicking a link using htmlunit (Java)

Tags: java, dom, htmlunit

I'm trying to get htmlunit to click the second link (`Contacts`) in a page:

```
<ul role="tablist">
<li class="nav-item nav-item-game active" data-nav="game" title="Game" role="presentation">
<a class="nav-lnk" aria-selected="true" role="tab" tabindex="0">
<span class="offscreen">Game</span>
<b class="icon icon-game"></b>
</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item nav-item-contacts" data-nav="contacts" title="Contacts" role="presentation">
<a class="nav-lnk" aria-selected="false" role="tab" tabindex="-1">
<span class="offscreen">Contacts</span>
<b class="icon icon-contacts"></b>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Right now I'm retrieving all links in the list:

```
List<DomNode> contactTabs = (List<DomNode>) gameLoggedInPage.getByXPath("//a[@class='nav-lnk']/)");
DomNode contacts = contactTabs.get(1);
```

How can I click on the second link from htmlunit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<HtmlAnchor> contactTabs = (List<HtmlAnchor>) gameLoggedInPage.getByXPath("//a[@class='nav-lnk'])");
HtmlAnchor contacts = contactTabs.get(1);
HtmlPage page = contacts.click();
```